# Get value from Picker onValueChange in react-native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am developing an app using react native.
Already I have implemented a list of user data. One example of data is this.

```
UID234 {"name":"Chris","age":31,"traits":{"eyes":"blue","shoe_size":10}}
```

Here's my code.

---

```
import RNPickerSelect from 'react-native-picker-select';

...


  <RNPickerSelect
     onValueChange={(value) => console.log(value)} // そのユーザーのvalueを取る
     // {console.log(to_user)}
    items={[
      { label: 'Chris', value: 'UID234' },
      { label: 'Marge', value: 'UID345' },
      { label: 'Yuri', value: 'UID456' }       
     ]}
     style={pickerSelectStyles}
     placeholder={{ label: '選択してください', value: '' }}
     />
```

In this case, when I select Chris, I can see "UID234" is shown on the console.

What I want to do is to print "Chris" on the screen.
How can I do that? Please help me...

Comment: As per official docs, onValueChange will return value and index. One thing you can change value also data also same as label if you don't use value for any other actions.

Answer (score 0):

The [react-native-picker-select](https://github.com/lawnstarter/react-native-picker-select) docs say the index can be passed in via the `onValueChange` callback. Use that to get the label.

```
import RNPickerSelect from 'react-native-picker-select';

...

const itemList = [
    { label: 'Chris', value: 'UID234' },
    { label: 'Marge', value: 'UID345' },
    { label: 'Yuri', value: 'UID456' }       
   ];

<RNPickerSelect
  onValueChange={(value, index) => console.log(itemList[index].label)} // <- get label from array
  // {console.log(to_user)}
  items={itemList}
  style={pickerSelectStyles}
  placeholder={{ label: '選択してください', value: '' }}
 />
```

Comment: Thank you, the name was successfully shown on the console. But, can I show the name, for example, "Chris" on the simulator screen?

Comment: I'm glad it worked! I am not sure what you mean by showing it on the simulator screen. If you want to use the selected value somewhere else you can set state in the `onValueChange`, and then use that state variable somewhere else on re-render.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to save the data in state form in order to show the label

```
this.state ={
  user : '' 
 }

<RNPickerSelect
    onValueChange={(value) => {this.setState({user: value,})}}
    items={[
      { label: 'Chris', value: 'UID234' },
      { label: 'Marge', value: 'UID345' },
      { label: 'Yuri', value: 'UID456' }       
     ]}
     style={pickerSelectStyles}
     value={this.state.user}
     placeholder={{ label: '選択してください', value: '' }}
     />
```